# Declaring JAXB as a dependency. Why?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jersey

Why would you want to declare JAXB as a dependency of your Java application since it's anyway shipped with the JRE and cannot be overriden in your applications classpath?

Using the [jersey-json](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.8/jersey-json-1.8.pom) as an example, in their POM file they declare a dependency to jaxb-impl without specifying the exact version even. What are they gaining by doing this?

And also, when I add a dependency to [jersey-json](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.8/jersey-json-1.8.pom) in my own POM file, I end up having jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar in my classpath. Why would I want this to happen? Isn't the default JVM implementation anyway getting loaded if I don't put the files to the endorsed libraries directory?

Comment: Can give the exact locations where you found the information about the pom's etc. ?

Comment: Added a link to the pom file of jersey-json.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing in the linked pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But there is also a parent pom, so you might want to follow that trail up, to see if an actual version and/or scope was specified there (and propagated down).

But if it isn't, then I'm guessing the Jersey team felt that the JAXB 2 API is mature enough to allow them to specify a loose dependency on the JAXB implementation.

The JRE ships with a specific implementation of the JAXB impl, which was equivalent to JAXB RI 2.1.7 for the longest time. But at the same time, there is a mechanism to easily swap out for another implementation of your choice, in your apps.

Sure you can use the built-in JRE JAXB implementation, and if it works for your app, you surely should try.

Nonetheless, some reasons that could lead you to want a separate JAXB implementation include : a left-over bug (addressed in a newer release); need a newer JAXB API such as JAXB 2.2.x (which comes in more recent version of the JRE); want to use a different implementation altogether (because it happens to have a better API and/or performance for your particular usage), etc...

So back to your jersey question, I'm guessing again that they wanted to give developers the flexibility to pull in their JAXB impl of choice. I'd think they have some level of recommendations somewhere in their guides.
However, the fact that the JAXB RI is specifically marked as a dependency, undercuts the argument.

Comment: In The parent the scope is not defined which results in having the dependency in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but this still doesn't clarify it completely for me. In my understanding you cannot simply override the version bundled with the JRE by adding another version to your classpath because for this you need to use the endorsed standards override mechanism (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards).

Or am I completely mistaken here?

I understand that for the Jersey project the exact version of JAXB makes a lot of difference but I don't understand how they can manage it in their pom file and why they define it as a compile time dependency.

Answer (score 0):

That sound like the jersey people defined their dependency wrong. If a dependency is provided by the environment where you run it should be defined with the scope "provided".

Comment: But why would you have it even as "provided" in this case since it's bundled in the rt.jar itself?

Comment: No. Cause you need it as compile dependency. But if you are sure to use always Java 1.6 than you really don't need it.